# Merge 2 data frames with common columns and add indicator when common value is not NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 data frames:

df_1:

```
  Date                time_series_1           time_series_2       
1  01-01-2019               NA                      10                      
2  02-01-2019               5                       NA                       
3  03-01-2019               10                      NA                          
4  04-01-2019               20                      6
```

df_2:

```
  Date                time_series_1           time_series_2            time_series_3
1  01-01-2019               NA                      10                       10
2  02-01-2019               5                       NA                       87
3  03-01-2019               10                      NA                       45   
4  04-01-2019               20                      6                        221
```

Both Data frames hase common columns: time_series_1 and time_series_2. (All columns in df_1 are contained in df_2)

My goal is to merge this 2 data frames, display the mergerd data frame in long format and add indicator if a specific value velongs to df_1 and is not NA in specific day.

The desired output will be:
DF_LONG_MERGED:

```
  Date                variable           value            indicator
1  01-01-2019      time_series_1          NA                  0
2  01-01-2019      time_series_2          10                  1
3  01-01-2019      time_series_3          10                  0  
4  02-01-2019      time_series_1          5                   1
5  02-01-2019      time_series_2          NA                  0            
6  02-01-2019      time_series_3          87                  0           
7  03-01-2019      time_series_1          10                  1            
8  03-01-2019      time_series_2          NA                  0 
9  03-01-2019      time_series_3          45                  0
10 04-01-2019      time_series_1          20                  1  
11 04-01-2019      time_series_2          6                   1 
12 04-01-2019      time_series_3          221                 0
```

Any suggestions about how to add this indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_1 %>% pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = 'variable') %>% mutate(indicator = case_when(!is.na(value) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% right_join(
df_2 %>% pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = 'variable') 
) %>% mutate(indicator = replace_na(indicator, 0)) %>% arrange(Date)
Joining, by = c("Date", "variable", "value")
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   Date       variable      value indicator
   <chr>      <chr>         <int>     <dbl>
 1 01-01-2019 time_series_1    NA         0
 2 01-01-2019 time_series_2    10         1
 3 01-01-2019 time_series_3    10         0
 4 02-01-2019 time_series_1     5         1
 5 02-01-2019 time_series_2    NA         0
 6 02-01-2019 time_series_3    87         0
 7 03-01-2019 time_series_1    10         1
 8 03-01-2019 time_series_2    NA         0
 9 03-01-2019 time_series_3    45         0
10 04-01-2019 time_series_1    20         1
11 04-01-2019 time_series_2     6         1
12 04-01-2019 time_series_3   221         0
```